# Difference between Web server threads and Application threads

Tags: multithreading, webserver, application-server

I want to know the diff between 1) Web server threads which take the http requests and send back the response to the clients 2) Application threads inside JVM which work on the requests coming to application server.

I know where we configure web server threads. Is there any file for creating thread pool for application threads?